# Modificar fichero XML con Java

Tags: java, xml

Necesito modificar un fichero XML, sobreescribir el mismo fichero pero cambiando solo la etiqueta 'fec' para que contenga la fecha actual.
El XML es el siguiente:

```
<Document>
    <Cst>
        <Grp>           
            <Ini>
                <Nm>Uruguay</Nm>
            </Ini>
        </Grp>
        <Pmti>
            <Pmt>111111</Pmt>
            <PmtM>XXX</PmtM>
            <Nb>1</Nb>
            <Ctrl>10</Ctrl>
            <Fec>2020-07-04</Fec>
            <Dbtr>
                <Nm>UY</Nm>
                <Ps>
                    <Ctry>UY</Ctry>
                </Ps>
            </Dbtr>
        </Pmti>
    </Cst>
</Document>
```

El fichero que se tiene que generar tiene que contener la misma información que el fichero actual y con el mismo nombre, sólo cambiando la fecha por el día actual.
Me gustaría saber como se hace con FileWritter y PrintWritter que es lo que estoy manejando en estos momentos. Actualmente tengo el siguiente código pero sólo consigo que el nuevo fichero se quede en blanco.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class AutomRegresionFecha {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            
            Date actual = new Date();
            String fecha = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(actual);
//            System.out.println(fecha);
            
//            String newCad = "<ReqdExctnDt>"+fecha+"<ReqdExctnDt>";
           
            //Leer fichero
            String linea1 = null;
            String path = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/prueba java/base/";
            BufferedReader comp1 = null;
            File filesBase = new File (path);
            File[] listaBase = filesBase.listFiles();
            
            //Crear fichero
            FileWriter fichero = null;
            PrintWriter pw = null;
            
            
            for (int b = 0; b < listaBase.length; b++) {
                
                comp1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(listaBase[b]));
//              System.out.println(listaBase[b].getName());
                
//              fichero = new FileWriter(path + listaBase[b].getName());
//              pw = new PrintWriter(fichero);
                
                
                    String linea = "";
                
                    while ((linea1 = comp1.readLine()) != null){
                        
                        String rulo = "";
//                      System.out.println(linea1);
                        if(linea1.contains("<ReqdExctnDt>")){
                            
//                          System.out.println(linea1);
                                
                                linea = rulo;
                                rulo = "";
                                
                                if(linea.indexOf("<Document><Cst><Pmti><Fec>") > -1) {
                                    System.out.println("linea: " + linea);
                                    int inicio = linea.indexOf("<Document><Cst><Pmti><Fec>");
                                    
                                    int fin = linea.indexOf("</", inicio + 1);
                                    
                                    String reemplazar = linea.substring(inicio + 0, fin);
                                    
                                    String uu = linea.replace(reemplazar, "<Document><Cst><Pmti><Fec>"+ fecha);
                                    
                                    rulo = uu;
                                }else  rulo = linea;
                            
                        }                       
                                    
                }               
            }       
            
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hay clases para hacer eso https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para parsear un XML, es mejor que lo hagas con las clases y utilidades que te ofrece Java para esto. Hacerlo mediante `indexOf` buscando las cadenas que necesitas es peligroso y más complicado ya que si el formato original del texto cambia ya no funcionará tu código. Utiliza esto en su lugar:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
      throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException, XPathExpressionException, TransformerException {
    String path = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/prueba java/base/";
    File filesBase = new File (path);
    File[] listaBase = filesBase.listFiles();
    
    for(File file : listaBase) {
      DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document doc = docBuilder.parse(file);

      XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
      Node node = (Node) xpath.evaluate("/Document/Cst/Pmti/Fec", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

      node.setTextContent(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date()));

      TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
      Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
      DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
      FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
      StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
      transformer.transform(source, result);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Como sería posible hacer lo mismo sin usar un bucle iterable. Es decir, con un bucle for normal. Es simple curiosidad para saber como  se cambia de uno a otro. Gracias.

Comment: Te refieres a sustituirlo por un for con índice? Simplemente tienes que sustituirlo por esto: 

`for(int i = 0; i < listaBase.length; i++) { File file = listaBase[i];`

Comment: Eso es si, entonces el parametro que se le pasaría a docBuilder sería listBase[1].toString() ?? para que siga cogiendo el mismo fichero

Comment: Vale si perdon seria listBase[i].toString(). Muchas gracias